# can not use rabbitmq config in docker build OS X

Tags: macos, configuration, rabbitmq, docker

Initially I was setting the rabbitmq config file like this (Dockerfile):

```
  RUN echo "[{rabbit, [{loopback_users, []}]}]." > /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

But now I need to configure the shovel plugin and would like to use an actual config file from source. To start out simple, the config file only contains the loopback_users setting. Here's the Dockerfile statements:

```
  ENV RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
  ADD rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
  #failed user setup script
  #ADD rabbitmq_userconfig.sh /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_userconfig.sh
  #RUN chmod 755 /usr/sbin/rabbitmq_userconfig.sh
```

This doesn't fail per se because rabbit starts and I can get to the web interface but the guest account isn't allowed to log in because I have to use a diff IP than localhost and need the looopback setting to be applied. So this tells me that the loopback_users setting wasn't applied.

rabbitmq is started via supervisor, the process starts successfully:

```
  [program:rabbitmq-server]
  command=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server
  environment=RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq
  priority=200
```

To get around the guest/localhost issue I tried adding a new user running a script after the image started but the process errors. I can't get to the root cause because I can't hook into the running container to run nsenter or any other diagnostic tool. I'm not very Linux savvy so my knowledge is basic.

There seems to be some disconnect while running docker via boot2docker on OS X. I had similar issues trying to configure elasticsearch and ended up configuring es via a nodejs app - not pleased. I don't want to resort to another hack like that.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an expert in rabbitmq but, shouldn't that `ENV RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq` be replaced by that `ENV RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`

Comment: No, it shouldn't, RabbitMQ add `.config` automatically, see [Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-location) section of RabbitMQ docs for the details

Comment: Does RabbitMQ has something suspicious in logs?

Comment: @zaq178miami I can't get to the logs. I can't get into the running container to see anything - I think it's an OSX issue running docker from what I can tell. I've been advised to use nsenter but that isn't working out for me :-). Thanks for replying. I'm going to strip the config file and add one thing at a time to try and pinpoint the breaking config item. Thanks!